# Converting NAD 83 State Plane Maryland Feet Coordinates from lat/long and vice versa using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-states, nad83

I need to convert a list of lat/lon points (in.csv file) into NAD 83 State Plane Maryland Feet and vice versa.

I know it can be done using ArcGIS, but I only have QGIS.

I am also quite new to QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import your csv file into QGIS (`Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...`)
2. Select the relevant CRS if prompted
3. If not prompted, right-click the point layer, select `Save As...` then choose `ESRI Shapefile` as format, and select the relevant CRS:

   [image: CRS options]

   *Note: always use the `Save As...` option when converting to different a CRS.*

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understood the logic. 
 I chose the CRS NAD_1983_StatePlane_Maryland_FIPS_1900_Feet and I get an error when I try to save as a shape file
* Export to vector file failed. Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to open Shapefile `dc_MaryShape.shp'.)

I tried to save it as a csv and I have this error: 
* Export to vector file failed. Error: Feature write errors: Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed to create ./dc_mary.csv:Permission denied)

Comment: @user73130 - Try to write the shapefile/csv in a directory where you have permission (e.g. Desktop). If the error still persists, you could consider uploading your data on a public server so that others could test it and determine if the fault lies with the files themselves or something else.